# First load in nextJs

Tags: node.js, next.js13, nextjs-image, nextjs-dynamic-routing

i create a website for my client ,it works fast and response time is to good in my local mechine , but when i deploy it on the aws ec2 sever , the response time is to slow and first load is about >10s , https://www.bookyourgift.in/.  , anyone suggest me any solution

Web devlopment and learning

Comment: can you show code fetch API?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.